# I cannot get into my iCloud account

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, apple-id

I'm trying to get into my iCloud account on my new Macbook. However, when I try, it asks me to verify with a code it can send to either my other Macbook (which no longer works) or to a phone number which I no longer have.
I would create a new account, but whatever new id I type, it just says "You cannot create a new account with an existing id", and tells me to log into my old account, which I can't do.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Apple Account Recovery process by going to:

https://iforgot.apple.com

You can read more about it, including tips for making it go faster here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921